# hear someone + gerund / infinitive / bare infinitive

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-structure

I was wondering whether all the following constructions are correct? If so, how they differ in meaning?
If the aren't, then which one is incorrect and why?

> **a-** You never hear her **bad-mouthing** someone else. 
> **b-** You never hear her **to bad-mouth** someone else. 
> **c-** You never hear her **bad-mouth** someone else.

Comment: I don't recognise the second one as grammatical. The other two are both fine, and I can't detect any difference in meaning.

Comment: She was not heard to say things like that. Otherwise, hear doesn't take "to".